# how to reduce blue light in xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu

I want to reduce the blue light of my screen, I thought it would be easy, but I have trouble doing this :

#### blue light

most internet answers are for ubuntu (not xubuntu) and propose this solution : settings > display > blue light, but I don't find it under my release of xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

#### flux

then i tried to use flux, but i couldn't install it, https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui, ppa didn't work and the workaround was not clear, maybe i misunderstood something, but it's using redshift anyway

#### redshift

so I tried to use redshift, https://github.com/jonls/redshift, but unfortunately i couldn't :

- first i got geoclue error https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/318
- then I tried a manual configuration with a config file, but I couldn't get it work, redshift gives me an `fopen: permission denied` : following instruction of the readme, I installed the config file in `~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf`, I had to create `~/.config/redshift/` first, and I changed the permissions to try to solve the issue :

  - `~/.config/` was **rwxr-xr-x**
  - `~/.config/redshift/` was **rwxrwxr-x**
  - `~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf` was **rw-rw-r--**
  - i made all of them **rwxrwxr-x**, but without luck
- and finally i could launch it with this command but then I cannot control the time : `redshift -l LAT:LONG` so it's not what I want

do you have a solution to reduce the blue light in xubuntu 22.04 ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `redshift`?   I've been using it since ~14.04 & prefer it even if I'm not using Xubuntu/Xfce; as it works in all desktops without change (GNOME's Night Light for example is for GNOME only). I don't understand your redshift issue; and you didn't provide specific details as to how you tried to use it (ie. I've used default version since 16.04) or provide your `redshift.conf` for example...

Comment: the conf file is just the default one found here https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/master/redshift.conf.sample, the pbm is not the content : it doesn't open, with the error `fopen: permission denied`. The command`redshift` alone gives me the geoclue error as mentionned with the link, and none of the solution proposed in the issue page worked for me. I can run it with this command : `redshift -l LAT:LONG` but i want to have control on the times it changes the light, not something based on geographical position

Comment: You mention where you get your source, github sources are usually for the latest version of the software (*closest to the lunar I'm using, but you're on a stable LTS release so may have older software, did you verify it's valid for your version?*) but did you place it in the correct location on your system? and most importantly with correct file permissions?  as permission denied implies you did not & your major issue is HOW you placed it on you local file-system... but you gave no specifics.  It reads as an operator error in your getting & placing the conf file on your system

Comment: I puted the conf file in `~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf` as stated in the faq of the readme file on github, because the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` env variable is empty on my system. I launched `redshift -c .config/redshift/redshift.conf`, I had to create `~/.config/redshift/` first, the permissions for `.config/` where `rwxr-xr-x`, for `.config/redshift/` it was `rwxrwxr-x`, and for `.config/redshift/redshift.conf` it was `rw-rw-r--`. I changed all of them for 777 (`rwxrwxrwx`) but i still get the same error.

Comment: ho yes, you where right about the version : I didn't notice there where three versions of the readme, on the second one they gives a different location, and it worked ! `.config/redshift.conf`

Comment: This site isn't a forum, but a Q&A site.  Please add additional details to your question (where it's easier to read & greater formatting options exist).  I don't have time to read that comment, which was made to the OP (or yourself) anyway given it was written as a comment.

Comment: FYI:  If you've solved it, you can write your own answer (*and gain rep*).  You can credit me via reference to comments if you like, but well done for solving it if you did!   *Please add additional details in future to your question, but you can add them to an answer if appropriate there instead & you write one*

Answer (score 2):

after discussion with @guiverc in the comments, I found the solution :

the readme page had versions, and the last one was not the right one for me, I had to place the config file in `~/.config/redshift.conf`